# Azure web job function status is Never Finished

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have created a web job in azure. The web job is a type of run continuously.The web job function invoked when there will be a message in a queue. I am able to invoke web job function by adding a message in queue by either by azure storage explorer or by mvc web app.

The web job is a console application which is taking a time around one hour to perform a work by running with command line locally. Upon invoking the web job its started successfully but after some time (around 5-10 minutes), I am finding the function Invoke status as "Never Finished" in web job log.

So my question are following:-

1) Is this problem due to long running task.

2) Is this problem due to any error during processing.(But I can run it locally)

3) If I delete the record from database added by web job then I find that web again started. Why?

4)If I need to delete the message from queue after completion of process?

Here is my snippet of code which is invoked from web job

```
namespace Scheduler
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        JobHost host = new JobHost();
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("webjobschedularargs")] string schedularargs,
                                  [Blob("containername/blobname")]TextWriter writer)
    {
        //writer.WriteLine(inputText);
        string[] args = schedularargs.Split(new char[0]);

        RunProcess(args);
        writer.WriteLine(schedularargs);
    }

    private static void RunProcess(string[] args)
    {
        if (!Initialize())
        {
            // Log issue
            Console.WriteLine("Error!!! Unable to initialize.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);

            // We're done
            return;
        }

        #region Run processor

        var options = new Options();
        var timer = new Stopwatch();

        if (CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing: ");
            timer.Start();

            if (options.Profiles != null)
            {
                foreach (var profile in options.Profiles)
                {
                    Console.Write(profile + ", ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            if (options.Reports != null)
            {
                foreach (var report in options.Reports)
                {
                    Console.Write(report + ", ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            var processor = new Processor(options);
            processor.Start();
        }

        #endregion
        // Log reason why not valid command args

        //-----call run processor function

        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Total time (ms): " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Done!!! Everything went ok.");

        //#if LOCAL
        //            Console.ReadKey(true);
        //#endif
    }



    private static bool Initialize()
    {
        // Set ninject values
        NinjectConfig.Start();

        // TODO: Set automapper values ??

        return true;
    }
}
```

}

edited:-

I'm getting following error in azure..

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.UpdateMessage(CloudQueueMessage message, TimeSpan visibilityTimeout, MessageUpdateFields updateFields, QueueRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.UpdateQueueMessageVisibilityCommand.TryExecute()

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.LinearSpeedupTimerCommand.Execute()

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.IntervalSeparationTimer.RunTimer(Object state)

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state)

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at 
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: ERR ]    at 
System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: INFO] .....................................................................................................................................................
[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 0 seconds

[07/10/2014 15:50:52 > 32a9e0: SYS INFO] Status changed to PendingRestart

[07/10/2014 15:50:57 > 32a9e0: SYS INFO] Run script 'Scheduler.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'

[07/10/2014 15:50:57 > 32a9e0: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running

So looking at the error I have tried to executing same function from console app locally and its works.After running multiple time I found that function is executing for 5 minutes exactly.So if there is any time bound to run any function in web jobs.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the code that is invoked?

Comment: Did you enable AlwaysOn for your Website?  If your task is taking this long to run, the worker process could be getting terminated because of inactivity.

Comment: Sorry Rick for not to mention, the web site is currently in free mode.But I think it should still work for at least 20 minutes. I will request my client to upgrade further.

Comment: Amit, Processor.Start() method executing a parallel loop to extract data from facebook and store it into database. So if parallel loop is creating problem?

Comment: For free websites you have a 2.5 minutes of CPU time quota for every 5 minutes of clock time. Since your job is taking more than that, the website is killed because it reached the quota and the webjob stops.

Comment: Now I have upgraded the site in standard mode.I have also set Always On feature for the site in configuration panel. But still I found the same issue.The web job working for around 5-6 minutes then show me status as "Never Finished". In toggle output I can find a error "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found". Hence I have tried to run console app from my computer by adding message in queue with azure storage explorer and found that its working fine and run for around 45 minutes. Can not find any exception locally.Please help.

Comment: I think it may issue because I'm adding and running web job inside a web site so it has a time a time out period. Because when I'm executing same method from console application it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bug in the WebJobs sdk where it is not creating the blob containers that should have been created by default, depending on when and where storage accounts are created.  What I had to do was create the containers myself.

They are:

azure-jobs-host-output
azure-webjobs-hosts

That resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem can arise if, in a function call, unicode characters are passed to the logger object. Apparently unicode isn't supported and something in the cleanup process goes bad and the job is never closed.